# Deleted documents when using Elasticsearch API from Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm relatively new to `Elasticsearch` and am having a problem determining why the number of records from a python`dataframe` is different than the indexes document count `Elasticsearch`.

I start by creating an index by running the following:   As you can see there are 62932 records.

I'm creating an index in elasticsearch using the following:
[Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzIMU.png)

When I check the index in `Kibana Management/Index Management` there are only 62630 documents.   According to Stats window there were 302 deleted count.  I don't know what this means.

Below is the output from the STATS window

`{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "stats": {
    "uuid": "egOx_6EwTFysBr0WkJyR1Q",
    "primaries": {
      "docs": {
        "count": 62630,
        "deleted": 302
      },
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 4433722
      },
      "indexing": {
        "index_total": 62932,
        "index_time_in_millis": 3235,
        "index_current": 0,
        "index_failed": 0,
        "delete_total": 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
        "delete_current": 0,
        "noop_update_total": 0,
        "is_throttled": false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "get": {
        "total": 0,
        "time_in_millis": 0,
        "exists_total": 0,
        "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
        "missing_total": 0,
        "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
        "current": 0
      },
      "search": {
        "open_contexts": 0,
        "query_total": 140,
        "query_time_in_millis": 1178,
        "query_current": 0,
        "fetch_total": 140,
        "fetch_time_in_millis": 1233,
        "fetch_current": 0,
        "scroll_total": 1,
        "scroll_time_in_millis": 6262,
        "scroll_current": 0,
        "suggest_total": 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
        "suggest_current": 0
      },
      "merges": {
        "current": 0,
        "current_docs": 0,
        "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "total": 2,
        "total_time_in_millis": 417,
        "total_docs": 62932,
        "total_size_in_bytes": 4882755,
        "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 20971520
      },
      "refresh": {
        "total": 26,
        "total_time_in_millis": 597,
        "external_total": 24,
        "external_total_time_in_millis": 632,
        "listeners": 0
      },
      "flush": {
        "total": 1,
        "periodic": 0,
        "total_time_in_millis": 10
      },
      "warmer": {
        "current": 0,
        "total": 23,
        "total_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "query_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 17338,
        "total_count": 283,
        "hit_count": 267,
        "miss_count": 16,
        "cache_size": 4,
        "cache_count": 4,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "fielddata": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "completion": {
        "size_in_bytes": 0
      },
      "segments": {
        "count": 2,
        "memory_in_bytes": 22729,
        "terms_memory_in_bytes": 17585,
        "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 2024,
        "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "norms_memory_in_bytes": 512,
        "points_memory_in_bytes": 2112,
        "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 496,
        "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
        "file_sizes": {}
      },
      "translog": {
        "operations": 62932,
        "size_in_bytes": 17585006,
        "uncommitted_operations": 0,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 55,
        "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
      },
      "request_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0,
        "hit_count": 0,
        "miss_count": 0
      },
      "recovery": {
        "current_as_source": 0,
        "current_as_target": 0,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "docs": {
        "count": 62630,
        "deleted": 302
      },
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 4433722
      },
      "indexing": {
        "index_total": 62932,
        "index_time_in_millis": 3235,
        "index_current": 0,
        "index_failed": 0,
        "delete_total": 0,
        "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
        "delete_current": 0,
        "noop_update_total": 0,
        "is_throttled": false,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "get": {
        "total": 0,
        "time_in_millis": 0,
        "exists_total": 0,
        "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
        "missing_total": 0,
        "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
        "current": 0
      },
      "search": {
        "open_contexts": 0,
        "query_total": 140,
        "query_time_in_millis": 1178,
        "query_current": 0,
        "fetch_total": 140,
        "fetch_time_in_millis": 1233,
        "fetch_current": 0,
        "scroll_total": 1,
        "scroll_time_in_millis": 6262,
        "scroll_current": 0,
        "suggest_total": 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
        "suggest_current": 0
      },
      "merges": {
        "current": 0,
        "current_docs": 0,
        "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "total": 2,
        "total_time_in_millis": 417,
        "total_docs": 62932,
        "total_size_in_bytes": 4882755,
        "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 0,
        "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 20971520
      },
      "refresh": {
        "total": 26,
        "total_time_in_millis": 597,
        "external_total": 24,
        "external_total_time_in_millis": 632,
        "listeners": 0
      },
      "flush": {
        "total": 1,
        "periodic": 0,
        "total_time_in_millis": 10
      },
      "warmer": {
        "current": 0,
        "total": 23,
        "total_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      "query_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 17338,
        "total_count": 283,
        "hit_count": 267,
        "miss_count": 16,
        "cache_size": 4,
        "cache_count": 4,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "fielddata": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0
      },
      "completion": {
        "size_in_bytes": 0
      },
      "segments": {
        "count": 2,
        "memory_in_bytes": 22729,
        "terms_memory_in_bytes": 17585,
        "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 2024,
        "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "norms_memory_in_bytes": 512,
        "points_memory_in_bytes": 2112,
        "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 496,
        "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
        "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
        "file_sizes": {}
      },
      "translog": {
        "operations": 62932,
        "size_in_bytes": 17585006,
        "uncommitted_operations": 0,
        "uncommitted_size_in_bytes": 55,
        "earliest_last_modified_age": 0
      },
      "request_cache": {
        "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
        "evictions": 0,
        "hit_count": 0,
        "miss_count": 0
      },
      "recovery": {
        "current_as_source": 0,
        "current_as_target": 0,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      }
    }
  }
}`

why does the doc count differ from the index total?   I've exported the data and the number of records matches the doc count.   How can I find out why documents were deleted and make sure they are not in the future?

Comment: This is not a good question, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . On my case, it count nested field documents

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

- Deleted documents tie up disk space in the index.
- In-memory per-document data structures, such as norms or field data, will still consume RAM for deleted documents.
- Search throughput is lower, since each search must check the deleted bitset for every potential hit. More on this below.
- Aggregate term statistics, used for query scoring, will still reflect deleted terms and documents. When a merge completes, the term statistics will suddenly jump closer to their true values, changing hit scores. In practice this impact is minor, unless the deleted documents had divergent statistics from the rest of the index.
- A deleted document ties up a document ID from the maximum 2.1 B documents for a single shard. If your shard is riding close to that limit (not recommended!) this could matter.
- Fuzzy queries can have slightly different results, because they may match ghost terms.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current//cat-indices.html
https://www.elastic.co/blog/lucenes-handling-of-deleted-documents